# ASP Link with parameter not passing

Tags: asp-classic

Sometimes a link with a parameter will bring up the parameter and sometimes it won't.  If I have IE open and doing things in other tabs and try to click the link with the parameter in it, it will come up to the main screen.  If I click the link without IE open, it goes to the site with the parameter.  Please help!

Sample Link: http://ServerName/time_and_attendance/?timesheet_id=7489

Code below:

```
<!--#INCLUDE virtual="/time_and_attendance/i_time_attendance_header.asp" -->
<%
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'JFV 6-10-2010:  Will need these lines uncommented and inserted above the '<!--#INCLUDE' line
'   to be used in the alternate e-mail configuration
'<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D" NAME="CDO for Windows 2000 Type Library" -->
'<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4" NAME="ADODB Type Library" -->
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %>
<%
'If there is not a timesheet id send user back to their employee page
If Request("timesheet_id")<>"" Then
    my_employees_timesheet_id=Request("timesheet_id")
    RedirectUrl="my_employees_timesheet.asp?timesheet_id="&Request("timesheet_id")
    'Response.Write my_employees_timesheet_id
Else
    Response.Redirect("default.asp")
End If
%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `Request.Querystring` instead of simply `Request`, and `Trim` the value before using it.

Also, `dim` a variable and retrieve the parameter into the variable first.

```
dim ts_id 

ts_id = trim(request.querystring("timesheet_id"))

If ts_id <>"" Then

    my_employees_timesheet_id=ts_id 

    RedirectUrl="my_employees_timesheet.asp?timesheet_id="&ts_id 

    'Response.Write my_employees_timesheet_id

Else

    Response.Redirect("default.asp")

End If
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I appreciate the help!